# UPDATE the column value in table depending on current value of the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Customers and it has a column called Balance. If the balance of the customer ends with '00', say 3000 then it should be updated to 30.00 in other cases like 1333 it should not change the value.

I have been able to differ the values like 3000 from 1333 by using

```
SELECT Balance
from dbo.Customers
where SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Balance),1,2) = '00'
```

but cannot find anywhere how to convert those found values like 3000, 6000, 9000 to 30.00, 60.00 and 90.00

**EDIT 1**
while updating it is important to me to have the '.00' like 30.00 , doing 30, 60, 90 is NOT an option
And the datatype of the Balance column is NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: what is the data type of the column `Balance` ?

Comment: why are you using `nvarchar(max)` to store numeric value ?

Comment: My company wants us to keep datatype as nvarchar(MAX) for anything other than primary key. That's all the explanation I can provide

Comment: but this won't be flexible for you in the future. dealing with money fields as nvarchar will cost you lots of time and mistakes.

Comment: I know but it is what it is.. :(

Comment: will you have decimal values like `20.00` in the table ?

Comment: No, table initially will not have decimal values like 20.00

Comment: what if value is 60?, 40?, 30?

Comment: The table I am using doesn't have 2 digit values in balance but if it were to have values like 60, 40, 30 then it should remain as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`right(Balance, 2) = '00'` to check for required condition

perform the division `Balance / 100` then convert to `decimal(20,2)` and then again convert to `varchar`

```
select  Balance,
        case    when    right(Balance, 2) = '00'
        then    convert(varchar(20), convert(decimal(20,2), Balance / 100))
        else    Balance
        end
from    Customer
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed

Comment: @Rajas what if value is 60?

Answer (score 0):

here's your update script.

```
Update Customers set Balance =  
cast(cast(cast(Balance as decimal)/100.00 as numeric(36,2)) as nvarchar(max)) 
Where (cast(Balance as decimal)%10.00) = 0
```

Comment: You could just divide instead of round.

Comment: while you are at it, it would be better to use a `WHERE` clause rather than update every row.

Comment: This works great too ! Now I face conundrum of which one to mark as accepted... I can't even upvote your answer because I don't have "15 reputation" :((